# NextJS Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. on app experimental directory folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have the following issue on nextJS
I cannot add a new page in NextJS 13 using the app experimental directory folder.

I went to my directory /device/settings and this I got:

[image: settings page not found on browser]

This is the folder structure I have now:

[image: folder structure]

And this is the settings page inside the device folder inside the app directory 'app/device/settings.tsx' => 'device/settings'

[image: settings page code]

What could I be doing wrong I am a newbie on NextJS, could you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use folders in Next.js App Directory: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#creating-routes.

> Inside the app directory, **folders** are used to define routes.
>
> Each **folder** represents a route segment that maps to a URL segment.
> To create a nested route, you can nest folders inside each other.
>
> [image: Page files make route segments publicly accessible]

Comment: This is perfect, I thought the map at the end should be with the file itsel, not with the folder. Thanks, it works now !